# How can I declare multiple function pointer types in one typedef declaration?

Tags: c++, c++17, function-pointers, typedef

I can do

```
typedef int a, b;
```

but I can't do something like

```
typedef void(*the_name_1, *the_name_2)(...);
```

Is there a way do to typedef 2 function pointer types at the same time ?

Comment: What's wrong with `using the_name_1= void(*)(...); using the_name_2 = the_name_1;`?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. Just trying to figure out if a one-liner is possible.

Comment: one-liner is often possible, but more often not "good design" as it's less expressive and easy to make or miss a mistake.

Comment: Why would you want to do it, though? Both aliases will just name the same type and will be able to be used interchangeably, so it doesn’t provide any type safety to have both. The only reason I can imagine is adding a compatibility alias, but even then `typedef`ing one name to the other would be preferable.

Comment: That’s not the comma operator.

Comment: @user3840170 it's not about type safety in my case it's about readability. I have an encrypt and decrypt func that have the same return type and take the same argument types. And I don't really want to name the type `file_encrypt_or_decrypt_func` if that makes sense.

Comment: @DavisHerring what is it called then? It's definitely a compile-time "operator", just not the same as in runtime `c+=1, b++`.

Comment: @PinkTurtle: It’s just a comma that separates *init-declarator*s.  Operators are components of expressions; it would be silly to say that `:` is an operator that introduces a base class or that `;` is an operator that ends a statement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Multiple declaration in C/C++ is misleading as `*` is linked to variable and not to the type:

```
typedef int a, *b, (*c)();

static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, a>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<int*, b>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<int (*)(), c>);
```

So your one-liner would be

```
typedef void(*the_name_1)(...), (*the_name_2)(...);
```

Comment: I see. I'll write that in 2 lines then :-D

Comment: @PinkTurtle precisely as stated [in the ISO CPP core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-name-one)

Answer (score 1):

Let’s ignore the `typedef` for a moment.

```c
void (*the_name_1, *the_name_2)(...);
```

Keeping in mind that C declarations (and C++ as well, mostly) follow the rule of ‘declaration reflects use’, this says that `(*the_name_1, *the_name_2)` is an expression that can be invoked with whatever arguments, returning `void`.  This makes `the_name_2` a pointer to a function taking whatever and returning void, but it tells you nothing about the type of `the_name_1`, other than that it should be possible to dereference.

That is why [Jarod42’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71410942/3840170) has you write the argument list twice.  This way you say that both `the_name_1` and `the_name_2` can be dereferenced, then invoked with whatever, giving you `void`.  It’s entirely analogous to

```c
char foo[42], bar[69];
```

The only difference `typedef` makes is that the names declared become names of types that the otherwise-declared variables would have.